# how to select record of particular id if not availabe then select by default record

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one table

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>serving_name</th>
      <th>price</th>
      <th>store_id</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Select record where store_id = 1 if store_id 1 is not available then select 0 store_id record

How it is possible

Comment: exacly what are you looking for. Mysql query or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a query based on a condition then you can do this:

```
$this->db->select('whatever')->from('your_table');
if ($store_id == 1){ 
    $this->db->where('store_id', 1)
}else if($store_id == $something_else){ 
    // magic 
}
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If `$store_id` 0 is your template, and all other values are numeric and greater than 0, then do it in your SQL via `where`, `order by` and `limit` clauses.

`select * from store_table where store_id=42 or store_id=0 order by store_id desc limit 0,1`

Use your chosen framework's query engine, or do your own DB interface class/function with either the `mysqli` class/function family, or `PDO`.  If you go that route, then be sure to use prepared statements.